# Choose any 3 integers from a set so that 8 divides the product of them?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given $\text{A} = \{1, 2, ..., 100\}$. Choose $3$ numbers randomly from $\text{A}$ and multiply all of them. Find the probability that the product thus obtained, is a multiple of $8$ ?

I wonder if I have considered enough cases or not.

Let $a, b$ and $c$ are 3 numbers that we choose

Case 1: choose $8 ∣ a$; $b,c$ randomly

Case 2: choose $a, b, c \equiv 2 \pmod 8$

Case 3: choose $2 ∣ a, 4 ∣ b$; c randomly but $4 ∤ a, 8 ∤ b$

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Detail your calculations

Comment: Your case-oriented approach makes sense. It seems like you should keep going and work out the details. You've stated case 2 slightly wrong (consider 6 mod 8).

Comment: A slightly better approach would be to consider the _complement_ of the event. Less casework :)

Answer (score 1):

Let E be the event that the product of the $3$ numbers is divisible by $8$.

Let's consider $E^c$.

For the product to be such that it's not divisible by $8$, one of the following conditions have to be met.

1. (Event $X$) None of the three numbers is divisible by $8$.
2. (Event $Y$) Exactly one number is divisible by $2$ or $4$. Also, that number is not divisible by $8$
3. (Event $Z$) Exactly two numbers are divisible by $2$ but neither is divisible by $4$.

Now, in the set A, there are exactly $12$ numbers divisible by $8$. There are $13$ numbers divisible by $4$ but not by $8$. And $25$ divisible by $2$ but not by either of $4$ or $8$.

$50$ numbers are not divisible by any of $2$, $4$, or $8$.

So, the number of ways in which $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ can happen are as follows.

$$ \begin{align*}
n(X) &= \binom{50}{3} = 19600\\[0.5cm]
n(Y) &= \binom{38}{1} \cdot \binom{50}{2} = 46550\\[0.5cm]
n(Z) &= \binom{25}{2} \cdot \binom{50}{1} = 15000\\[0.5cm]
\end{align*} $$

Now $E^c$ is the union of the events $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. Also, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are mutually exclusive. So, the number of ways in which $E^c$ can happen would be

$$ \begin{align*}
n(E^c) &= n(X) + n(Y) + n(Z) \\[0.5cm]
&= 81150
\end{align*} $$

Finally,

$$ \begin{align*}
P(E) &= 1 - P(E^c) \\[0.5cm]
&= 1 - \frac{81150}{\binom{100}{3}} \\[0.5cm]
&\approx 0.498
\end{align*} $$