# The probability that 3 chosen numbers has product divisible by 8

Tags: probability

Less than a day ago, someone posted the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856479/choose-any-3-integers-from-a-set-so-that-8-divides-the-product-of-them):  **I choose three numbers from 1 to 100 (without replacement).  What's the probability that their product is divisible by 8?**

Someone kindly provided a solution describing how to calculate this probability by calculating the chance that it *doesn't* happen.  I want to calculate this probability directly, but I keep getting stuck (with Monte carlo, I am fairly certain that the answer already given is correct, around 0.49).

Here's what I have.  There are three cases:

- I draw a sequence with 2 odd numbers and 1 even.  Then the even must be divisble by 8.  Since there are 12 numbers less than 100 divisible by 8, there are ${12 \choose 1}\cdot{50 \choose 2}$ possibilities.
- I draw a sequence with 1 odd number and 2 evens.  Then, one of the evens must be divisible by 4.  The other can be any even.  So I have there are ${25 \choose 1}\cdot {49 \choose 1} \cdot {50  \choose 1}$ possibilities.
- I draw a sequence with 3 evens.  There are ${50 \choose 3}$ possibilities.

Together, this gives me the probability

$$\frac{{12 \choose 1}\cdot{50 \choose 2} + {25 \choose 1}\cdot {49 \choose 1} \cdot {50  \choose 1} + {50 \choose 3}}{{100 \choose 3}} \approx .59$$

Where am I going wrong?  I want to calculate this probability directly, not as in the case with the other question.

Comment: In the other question the numbers are chosen without replacement and here you are mixing both with/without replacement.

Comment: @Kroki,  I'll edit the question.  But I think in terms of my reasoning, the only thing that would change is the case of two evens -- then I would have ${25 \choose 1}\cdot {49 \choose 1} \cdot {50  \choose 1}$ instead.

Comment: you need to fix in the formula as well.

Comment: @Kroki, thanks, the formula should be edited.  But this still isn't correct, this works out to around .59 still....

Comment: The two even case need to be separated to two divisible by $4$ and one divisible by $4$ and the other is not divisible by $4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix if you want with or without replacement:

- Without replacement:

$$\frac{\binom{12}{1}\binom{50}{2} + \binom{25}{2}\binom{50}{1} + \binom{25}{1}\binom{25}{1}\binom{50}{1}+ \binom{50}{3}}{\binom{100}{3}}$$

- With replacement:

$$\frac{3 \times 12 \times 50^2 + 6\times 25 \times 25 \times 50 + 3\times 25 \times 25 \times 50 + 50^{3}}{100^{3}}$$

Comment: I don't think the with replacement formula is correct, it works out to be about .59 which isn't supported by Monte Carlo trials.

Comment: Yes I fixed both formula

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you!  Because I'm considering the subset of even numbers that are divisible by 4, I need to split up both cases separately.  Thanks!